# Synchronized method not blocking other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, synchronized, java-threads

I've a singleton class like this:

```
private static StringsHandler INSTANCE = null;
private int count = 0;
//I have 2 methods so I don't have to be sending/checking nulls on getInstance
//once it's created
public static void createInstance(List<String> strings){
    if(StringsHandler.INSTANCE == null)
        StringsHandler.INSTANCE = new StringsHandler(strings);
}

public static StringsHandler getInstance(){
    return StringsHandler.INSTANCE;
}

public synchronized File use(){
    count++;
    System.out.println("threads using .use " + count);
    while(true){} //Keep the thread here so count should stay as 1
}
```

Instance is created on the application main class, main method just like this:

```
if(stringList.isEmpty()){
        LOGGER.error("List was empty");
        System.exit(0);
    }
StringsHandler.createInstance(stringList);
```

And I call it using something like this:

```
list.parallelStream().forEach(element -> {
    SingletonClass.getInstance().use();
});
```

This should print `threads using .use 1` but it prints `threads using .use 5` why is the synchronized keyword allowing for more than 1 thread?

Comment: Do you have more than one object?

Comment: How do you call this?

Comment: Edited to answer your questions

Comment: Show us SingletonClass.getInstance()

Comment: Post short but full example which will let us reproduce your problem [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't make us guess *what* went wrong, even if we guess that there is lower chance to guess and properly explain *why* part which may prevent us from suggesting proper solution.

Comment: Edited again, @Pshemo I'll try

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your bug is in SingletonClass.getInstance() so just show us this method and you will have your answer

Comment: And how createInstance is called?

Comment: show us how INSTANCE is declared?

Comment: MCVE means we should be able to copy the code and paste it into a file, then compile and run it. voted to close due to this not being a MCVE.

Comment: @NathanHughes That makes sense, specially on a question like this. Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce this on a MCVE way, so I'll close the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `synchronized` keyword only allows one thread to lock the particular object on which it is used. So if you have more than one instance of this object, and call `use` on more than one of them at a time, they will be able to execute at the same time.

It is your responsibility to decide on, and consistently enforce, a mapping of data elements to exclusion methods. If more than one exclusion method protects the same data element, then you will not get correct exclusion.

Comment: Forgot to mention I was using a singleton class, edited question.

Comment: Log the object identifier on entry to `use` and you'll see they're not the same object.

Comment: As long as `count` isn’t declared `static`, there still shouldn’t be any thread printing a value of `5`. Unless there is other code manipulating the variable…

Comment: It's actually a bit more complicated than that, it does print a number different from 1, but it only prints once.

Comment: @Holger there is not.

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez, sounds like the problem lies in code that you have not shown us.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm building a small class containing all the logic and flow to provide to you.